# PHP - Create method for an array of classes

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am using `SimpleXMLElement` to parse my XML and call the method `SimpleXMLElement::children()` to get all children from the XML. I do now have a problem, because I want to call a function that does not exist for an array of course.

My Classes:

`XmlResponse`: has an array of `Product` (this class extends SimpleXMLElement).

This means I can't just call `$xmlResponse->products->children()`, since `products` is only an array with `Product` objects and I can't call functions on an array.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Pls add structure of your xml to order to test my answer

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve here. Could you [edit] the question to add some sample code that demonstrates the problem? If you have a SimpleXML object, accessing `->children()` will return another object, not an array. And if you do have an array, what would calling `->children()` on it mean: all the children of all the objects in the array?